# Create a new nested object from array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, nested-object

I have nested array of objects as below:

```
[       
          {
            "i18n Key": "messages.titles.info",
            English: "Info",
            Spanish: "Info",
          },
          {
            "i18n Key": "messages.titles.export",
            English: "Export",
            Spanish: "Exportar",
          },
          {
            "i18n Key": "messages.common.pleaseWait",
            English: "Please Wait…",
            Spanish: "Por favor esperar…",
          },
          {
            "i18n Key": "messages.common.errors.couldNotAccessADGroup",
            English: "Could not access AD to get user groups. Please try again.",
            Spanish: "No se puede acceder a AD para buscar grupos de usuarios. Por favor inténtelo nuevamente.",
          },
          {
            "i18n Key": "labels.country.regulatorList.regulatorForm.regulatorName",
            English: "Regulator Name",
            Spanish: "Nombre del regulador",
          },
          {
            "i18n Key": "labels.country.regulatorList.regulatorForm.country",
            English: "Country",
            Spanish: "País",
          },
]
```

How can I convert it to a nested object like this?

```
{
    "messages": {
      "titles": {
        "info": "Info",
        "export": "Exportar",
      },
      "common":{
        "pleaseWait":  "Por favor esperar…",
        "errors": {
            "couldNotAccessADGroup": "No se puede acceder a AD para buscar grupos de usuarios. Por favor inténtelo nuevamente.",
        }    
      },
    }  
    "labels":{
        "country":{
            "regulatorList":{
                "regulatorForm":{
                    "regulatorName":  "Nombre del regulador",
                    "country": "País",
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The length of "i18n Key" is not fix, it can be of length 5,6,7 and so on.

it's bascially keeping spanish value corresponding to the last word of "i18n Key".

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use `String.split('.')` to separate "i18n key" into elements.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `i18n Key` value defines the structure of the output and it could change its length, I would suggest to use recursion to solve this problem.

### Solution

```js
// Input data
const descriptors = [
  {
    "i18n Key": "messages.titles.info",
    English: "Info",
    Spanish: "Info",
  },
  {
    "i18n Key": "messages.titles.export",
    English: "Export",
    Spanish: "Exportar",
  },
  {
    "i18n Key": "messages.common.pleaseWait",
    English: "Please Wait…",
    Spanish: "Por favor esperar…",
  },
  {
    "i18n Key": "messages.common.errors.couldNotAccessADGroup",
    English: "Could not access AD to get user groups. Please try again.",
    Spanish: "No se puede acceder a AD para buscar grupos de usuarios. Por favor inténtelo nuevamente.",
  },
  {
    "i18n Key": "labels.country.regulatorList.regulatorForm.regulatorName",
    English: "Regulator Name",
    Spanish: "Nombre del regulador",
  },
  {
    "i18n Key": "labels.country.regulatorList.regulatorForm.country",
    English: "Country",
    Spanish: "País",
  },
];

const sourceValue = 'Spanish';

const output = {};

const parseValue = (obj, value = undefined, keyMap = []) => {
  if (keyMap.length) {
    const propertie = keyMap.splice(0, 1);

    if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, propertie)) {
      obj[propertie] = {};
    }

    if (!keyMap.length) {
      obj[propertie] = value;
    } else {
      obj[propertie] = parseValue(obj[propertie], value, keyMap);
    }
  }
  return obj;
};

for (let i = 0; i < descriptors.length; i++) {
  const descriptor = descriptors[i];
  const keyMap = descriptor['i18n Key'].split('.');
  
  parseValue(output, descriptor[sourceValue], keyMap);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, 2));
```